# Trabalhar com centavos em C

Tags: c, float

No código  abaixo consigo receber valores nos campos de salário sem centavos (exemplo: 1,800), mas se coloco (1.800,20) apresenta erro.
Detalhe estou utilizando `setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");` .

```
printf("\nAntepenúltimo salário: ");
scanf("%f", &AntepenultimoSalario);

printf("\nPenúltimo salário: ");
scanf("%f", &PenultimoSalario);

printf("\nÚltimo salário: ");
scanf("%f", &UltimoSalario);

MediaSalario  = (UltimoSalario + PenultimoSalario + AntepenultimoSalario) / 3 ;

if(tempoServico >= 6 && tempoServico <= 11){
    printf("Ira receber 3 parcelas");
}else if(tempoServico >= 12 && tempoServico <= 23 ){
     printf("Ira receber 4 parcelas");
}else if(tempoServico >= 24 ){
     printf("Ira receber 5 ");
}else{
    semdireito();
}

// printf("Media Salario: %f", MediaSalario);

if(MediaSalario < 1.22277){
    SalarioFinal = (MediaSalario * 0.8) * 1000 ;
    printf(" parcelas : %5.3f\n", SalarioFinal);
    system("pause");
}else if(MediaSalario > 1.22278 && MediaSalario <= 2.03815){
    SalarioFinal2 = (MediaSalario - 1.22278) * 1000;
    SalarioFinal = (SalarioFinal2 * 0.5) + 978.22;
    printf(" parcelas de R$ %2.f\n", SalarioFinal);
    system("pause");
}else if(MediaSalario >= 2.03815){
    printf(" parcelas de R$ 1.385,91\n");
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/64969

Comment: Olhe minha resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/219465/64969, tem explicação sobre cálculos monetários usando ponto fixo (`BigDecimal` e afins) e ponto flutuante. Também faço menção a um ótimo vídeo do InfiniteSeries sobre números de pontos flutuantes

Comment: Preciso de orientação especifica no código acima, por gentiliza

Comment: não usar `float` para unidades monetárias?

Comment: Utilizo  `double` no caso @JeffersonQuesado ?

Comment: Também não. Tem os mesmos problemas. Veja a resposta supracitada para maiores criticismos ao uso desse tipo de dado.

Comment: Conforme citei no questionamento sou iniciante e preciso de ajuda aplicada no código acima

Comment: Por isso estou recomendando fortemente entender o criticismo quanto ao uso inadequado de um tipo de dados formulado para aplicações científicas em contextos que são extremamente sensíveis à precisão.

Comment: Entendi que esta incorreto utilizar `float`, porem não sei qual  utilizar

Comment: Notação de ponto fixo. Decimal de tamanho arbitrário. As opções mais comuns são essas. Ponto fixo pode não exigir estrutura, mas cuidado na manipulação.